# Unable to ping virtual machine, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, openwrt

I installed OpenWrt in VirtualBox with this network configuration:

- access bridge
- eth0
- type of card: PCnet-FAST III
- eth0 adress of OpenWrt is: 192.168.1.226
- eth0 adress of the OS installed in my PC(Ubuntu) is: 192.168.1.240

When I ping from Ubuntu to OpenWrt or from OpenWrt to Ubuntu, wireshark shows only packages sent from OpenWrt (192.168.1.226).

Can someone tell me why and help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check your virtual network settings.

You need to be in bridged mode for net0.

Also, you virtual network should be a different subnet from your host such as 192.168.2.x/24 and that network say net2 which would also need to be set to NAT.

Your virtual guest would have a network address in the net2 space such as 192.168.2.11/24.  Since net2 is in NAT mode and net0 is in bridged mode this will allow your guest access to your host and also your internet connection.